# Boolean operations on 2d rectangles

Tags: c++, algorithm, graphics, boolean

I have written my own rectangle class and it includes a method to subtract one rectangle from another.  The algorithm simply determines which edge the source rectangle is overlapping on the destination rectangle and then chugs through all possible cases, including being completely inside, just on the edge, completely enclosing and so on.  In fact there are so many cases I'm looking at the code and wondering if there are algorithms or examples of boolean operations on rectangles already available.

I know there are [generalised clipping algorithms for 2d polytopes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weiler%E2%80%93Atherton_clipping_algorithm) but I was looking for something specific to 2d rectangles, with the appropriate concomitant optimisations and simplifications.

Can anyone point me in the right direction, or is Weiler-Atherton the last word on this general class of problem of which the rectangle is just a single case?

Comment: What kind of output are you aiming for?  A set of rectangles?  A polygon?  I'd suggest starting with an "overlap" operation that returns the rectangle region in common, that subtracted area could be in any of 9 positions relative to the subtracted-from rectangle, but the same code can handle the 4 corner positions, other code 4 edge positions, so you've only got 3 meaningfully different cases....  (I wrote code to do this - handle stacks of rectangles each with set/reset/toggle behaviour, find simplest non-overlapping etc - earlier this year, but closed source - not my choice).

Comment: Sorry forgot to add that:  the algorithm I made returns a set of rectangles rather than a polygon, i.e. it's only ever dealing in rectangles.  It's for a windowing system actually (windows are always rectangles).

Answer (score 1):

If you separate the two directions, you have only a few base cases, which you can then combine in a nested loop.

The base cases are sketched below:

```
               |              |
       XXXXX   |..............|              1 section
               |              |
            XXXXXXX...........|              2 sections
               |              |
               |...XXXXXXX....|              3 sections
               |              |
               |..........XXXXXXXX           2 secions
               |              |
               |..............|   XXXX       1 section
               |              |
             XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX            nothing
               |              |
```

The vertical bars are the edges of the original rectangle, the `X` is the rectangle that is to be subtracted, the dots mark sections. `X` between the vertical bars are also sections that are kept, except when combined with an `X` section of the other direction. (If that sounds too complicated: The hole left behind is designated by the `X` section in both directions.

We can separate the directions by redesigning the rectangles properties left, top, right and bottom into arrays of min/max values:

```
typedef struct Rect Rect;

struct Rect {
    int min[2];
    int max[2];
};
```

(The code is C, not C++, I'm afraid.)

Then we can find the sections for each direction:

```
int rect_sub_dir(int sec[], int *skip, Rect a, Rect b, int dir)
{
    int n = 0;

    sec[n++] = a.min[dir];
    if (b.min[dir] > a.min[dir] && b.min[dir] < a.max[dir]) {
        sec[n++] = b.min[dir];
    }
    *skip = n - 1;
    if (b.max[dir] < a.max[dir] && b.max[dir] > a.min[dir]) {
        sec[n++] = b.max[dir];
    }
    sec[n] = a.max[dir];

    // Backpatch if rectangles don't overlap        
    if (b.max[dir] < a.min[dir]) *skip = -1;
    if (b.min[dir] > a.max[dir]) *skip = -1;

    return n;
}
```

This creates an array of `n + 1` boundaries, between `n` sections. The `skip` value denotes a section marked `X` between vertical bars.

You can then combine the sections of the two directions:

```
int rect_sub(Rect res[], Rect a, Rect b)
{
    int hor[4];
    int ver[4];

    int hskip, nhor;
    int vskip, nver;
    int h, v;
    int n = 0;

    nhor = rect_sub_dir(hor, &hskip, a, b, 0);
    nver = rect_sub_dir(ver, &vskip, a, b, 1);

    printf("%d, %d\n", hskip, vskip);

    for (h = 0; h < nhor; h++) {
        for (v = 0; v < nver; v++) {
            if (h == hskip && v == vskip) continue;

            res[n++] = rect(hor[h], ver[v], hor[h + 1], ver[v + 1]);
        }
    }

    return n;
}
```

This solution is not optimal. It will create eight rectangles when the second rectangle is contained in the first one, which may not be what you are looking for. You could always try to merge adjacent rectangles afterwards. Or you could rewrite the code to split the rectangles more intelligently.

I have tested the code with some cases, but because there are many possible arrangements, the code is not fully tested.

Comment: Looks great.  Will give it a try.  +1 for effort though I haven't studied it to see that it will work :p.  Will get back to you if I succeed.